# Is there a way for me to pivot these rows into columns in oracle?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, pivot

I have a database table which looks like the attached image

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9lQO4.png)
I need to query this and be able to show output in the format of
BookID, Genre1, Genre2, Genre3

I have read some previous posts on pivoting / use of the MAX function but I am still struggling, I am new to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `row_number()` and conditional aggregation:

```
select bookId,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then genre end) as genre_1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then genre end) as genre_2,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then genre end) as genre_3
from (select bg.*, 
             row_number() over (partition by bookId order by genre) as seqnum
      from bookGenres
     ) bg
group by bookId;
```

Comment: Great thanks that's really helpful. How would this work if I have one table named Books with the book id and name, second table named genre with the genre codes and the name of the genre, then bookgenre as my third with only the book id and genre id. (sorry if this is a stupid question) i.ie I need to go from book to bookgenre to genre

Comment: @va9999 . . . Then you would have a different question.  That should be asked as a NEW question.